# Problem setting a path for filesystemwatcher

Tags: powershell, user-interface, filesystemwatcher

I have a code that uses filesystemwatcher to monitor a folder in a path.

I need the path that it monitors to change based on inputs in a two fields, when entered by a user in a GUI. And it to start monitoring when a button is clicked.

I do have a GUI that works like this for starting a .bat file based on these two fields being filled out. (I actually need the same GUI to start both at the same time, as the first one opens a file and saves something out into the folder that this needs to monitor).

I can't seem to get the filesystemwatcher to run on the same click.

I have tried all sorts of ways to combine the two to work together but no joy.
But as I am new to any kind of coding I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the Filesystem watcher code that should run a .bat file when a file is sensed in the folder.
Folder1 & Folder2 need to be able to change based on the input int the GUI.

```
$folder = 'c:\Work\Folder1\Folder2\Destination' 
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\log\Filelog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
Set-Location "c:\Work\Folder1\Folder2\Destination"
Start-Process "c:\Work\Folder1\Folder2\Destination\PS_Run.bat"
}
```

Below is the way the existing (Run.bat) code works from the GUI

```
$TextBox.multiline = $false
$TextBox.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50)
$TextBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,50)
$TextBox.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'



$TextBox2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox2.multiline = $false
$TextBox2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,110)
$TextBox2.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,50)
$TextBox2.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

\Folder1\Folder2\
$($TextBox.text)\$($TextBox2.text)
```

The `$TextBox`  to  `$($TextBox.text)` works in one situation but not the other, and I need them to work together.

Error I get is

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name O:\EU_CGI_Resources\IMS\Automation_Tes
ting\Scripting\MaxScript\Texture_change_1\$($TextBox.text)\$($TextBox2.text)\Production\3D_Files\export is invalid."
At O:\EU_CGI_Resources\IMS\Automation_Testing\Scripting\Sctips_WIP\Watch_Path_Test.ps1:14 char:8
+ $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{I ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At O:\EU_CGI_Resources\IMS\Automation_Testing\Scripting\Sctips_WIP\Watch_Path_Test.ps1:16 char:22
+ Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Acti ...
+                      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Register-ObjectEvent], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObj
   ectEventCommand

Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At O:\EU_CGI_Resources\IMS\Automation_Testing\Scripting\Sctips_WIP\Watch_Path_Test.ps1:26 char:22
+ Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted -Acti ...
+                      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Register-ObjectEvent], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObj
   ectEventCommand
```

Comment: Add `-Wait -NoNewWindow` to your call to `Start-Process`.

Comment: The path doesn't get recognised with the $($TextBox.text)\$($TextBox2.text) in it.
On the filewatcher side